# FlowDocumentPageViewer - Styling zooming slider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styling

I am using FlowDocumentPageViewer control and I would like to override style of default zooming control inside of FlowDocumentPageViewer ( +/- buttons and slider) . How I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please elaborate your question and mention what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a custom template for the part PART_FindToolBarHost.

There is a complete example in the msdn library: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I just wanted to remove gradient from buttons, but if there is no simplier solution I will follow this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the control's `template` you can't just simply change those buttons. However, you can recreate their behavior:

**XAML**

```
<FlowDocumentPageViewer Name="myFlow">
    <FlowDocumentPageViewer.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Click="ZoomIn"/>
                <Button Click="ZoomOut"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </FlowDocumentPageViewer.Template>
</FlowDocumentPageViewer>
```

**CODE**

```
private void ZoomIn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myFlow.IncreaseZoom();
}

private void ZoomOut(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myFlow.DecreaseZoom();
}
```